# Action Bar Background color?- Play Newstand app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

How to change the action bar background color when ever i swipe the  viewpager,I saw the Google Play News Stand app.It looks gud when ever i swipe the page,does any body know how they did it?

[image: Sample 1] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try this by random background color picking...

```
final int[] colors={Color.BLACK,Color.CYAN,0xff1023ED,....};
    final Random random=new Random();
    .....

    oncreate(){
    ....
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colors[random.nextInt(2)]));
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank u but y should i enable tittle of action bar?

Comment: used to Set whether an activity title/subtitle should be displayed.I applied because,if it is disable we can make it enable by setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1):

implement
    `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`
change actionBar color in`onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)`using `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));`

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff096DED));
//mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: where i am using fragment in Viewpager,Can i add this code in Fragment ?

Comment: use on Viewpager listener

Comment: Y should i change setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);